# Spring Data Neo4j findAll() for depth>1 takes long time

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

By default findAll() method finds nodes for depth = 1. If I try to find nodes for depth greater than 1. For example findAll(2) it takes long time to compute the result. There are thousands of child nodes at level 2. I need an efficient way to get result for depth = 2.

Comment: Please share some more information- how long, how many nodes and relationships are loaded, what do you want to load and what is your graph model. Otherwise it is hard to help.

Comment: Match(c:company)-[r1]-(d)-[r2]-(e). My structure is somehow represented by this query. COUNT(c) = 7201, Count(r1) = 42574, Count(r2) = 20309295